# Django URL explanation

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm facing an issue in Django URLs which is when I direct to `localhost:8000/dashboard` or `localhost:8000/dashboard1111111111`, it opens the same page.

Although in my `urls.py` file I have only `/dashboard`

How do I throw an error page if URL is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `$` at the end of the regular expression:

```
url(r'^dashboard$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
```

This would require the end of the string after the `dashboard` word.